# How do i use jPanelMenu? (jquery menu plugin)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm no javascript ninja, but i'd like to incorporate this library in a site targeting tablets.  Here is the library :
[jPanelMenu](http://jpanelmenu.com/)

Here is my redered html:

```
   <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>


<script src="/Scripts/jPanelMenu-1.0.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

<header class="main">

        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="/">Overview</a></li>
            <li><a href="#usage">Usage</a></li>
            <li><a href="#inner-workings">Inner-Workings</a></li>
            <li><a href="#animation">Animation</a></li>
            <li><a href="#options">Options</a></li>
            <li><a href="#api">API</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tips">Tips &amp; Examples</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        </ul>
</header>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var jPM = $.jPanelMenu();
        jPM.on();
    });
</script>
<body>
```

All i see in the browser is a normal UL bulleted list.  No Js errors in chromes dev tools. Anyone ever use this plugin or know what im doing wrong?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Here is updated code with solution from dbaseman

```
<html>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>


<script src="/Scripts/jPanelMenu-1.0.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

<header class="main">
        <div class="menu-trigger">Click Me</div>
        <ul id="menu" style="display: none;">
            <li><a href="/">Overview</a></li>
            <li><a href="#usage">Usage</a></li>
            <li><a href="#inner-workings">Inner-Workings</a></li>
            <li><a href="#animation">Animation</a></li>
            <li><a href="#options">Options</a></li>
            <li><a href="#api">API</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tips">Tips &amp; Examples</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        </ul>
</header>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var jPM = $.jPanelMenu();
        jPM.on();
    });
</script>
<body>


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index.Tablet</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        tablet home
    </div>
</body>
</html>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a "trigger" element to enable the menu (it looks for `.menu-trigger` by default):

```
<div class="menu-trigger">Click me to trigger</div>
```

(Also, apparently it expects the menu element to be hidden initially, so use `<ul style="display: none;" ...>`.)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yCvD3/177/)

Comment: I have sub menus. Why all sub menus are expanded automatically?

Comment: When I click 'menu-trigger' element, it throws error as 'jPanelMenu.triggerMenu is not a function'

Comment: I need all sub-menus should not be expanded while clicking on 'menu-trigger' element. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change trigger to anchor tag

```
<a class="menu-trigger" href="#menu">Click Me</div>
```

You can see it in the Jpanelmenu webpage source.